# Flink fan-out flatMap

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Flink 0.10.0 DataStream.
Here's my requirement.

- My source system is a Custom system which broadcasts messages. In my custom SourceFunction implementation I have callbacks implemented to listen for messages.
- Each of the callbacks gets a different type of message.
- I would like to decode/convert the object received in the callback to send to my SinkFunction. This I believe I can do with a FlatMapFunction or similar.
- Since I have various callbacks that I listen to the decoding logic for each of them is different. I suppose cannot have a single FlatMapFunction for all of them as the IN type would be different.

How can I design a system which has the following topology:

Source
|- FlatMap_1 (processing message type received by callback 1) -> Sink
|- FlatMap_2 (processing message type received by callback 2) -> Sink
|- FlatMap_3 (processing message type received by callback 3) -> Sink
and so on.

I do not want to send the output of one to the other. This is essentially a Fan-Out i.e. I would like each of them to function in parallel and also would like the Source to be able to figure out which Operator to send the received message to.

I have been through the documentation and examples but am not able to find an example that matches this. Would appreciate help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `Split operator` which is explained at the end of the [DataStream API transformation section](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/streaming_guide.html#transformations). The Split operator directs one input stream into different output streams.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response and apologies for the late reply to you. Thanks this worked. I'm not sure how I could not get this from the docs :).